# How to use new ID for subsequent inserts in same transaction

Tags: oracle, triggers, guid

Using Oracle, we have 2 tables - Parent and Child.

We have the ID column as GUID in Parent table and this value is being created by a trigger before insert.

Now while inserting records in same transaction, I need to
- First add a record to Parent table, then
- Use the new GUID created in trigger to add records to child table

How do I retrieve this new GUID for subsequent inserts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `returning into` clause of `insert` statement

```
INSERT INTO parent VALUES (col1, ...)
  RETURNING <your id column > INTO < variable>;

insert into child (parent_id) values (< variable>);
```